# Trying to attach Adventureworks2012 on SQL Server 2019 gives error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, access-denied, sql-server-2019

I am trying to install AdventureWorks2012 data file on my system using SQL Server 2019. I am getting below error message.

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Any help or pointers how to resolve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "install" the data file? You don't "install" a database, you `CREATE`, `ATTACH` or `RESTORE` a database. What is the statement you are actually running tom get the error above?

Comment: Try running SSMS as Administrator.

Comment: Tried ATTACH option from SSMS and it works! Thank you!